# Angular JS - IpCookies not working properly on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm using ivpusic/angular-cookie package at the moment for my local app. I can set a simple cookie like this one:

```
ipCookie('force-premium', true, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

But, whenever I put in a domain name different than null, this won't work. For example, this wouldn't create a cookie for me

```
ipCookie('force-premium', true, { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: 'localhost' });
```

But somehow this works

```
ipCookie('force-premium', true, { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: '' });
```

What is the problem with this code? I need to set the domain name because  I want to create a domain-wide cookies as I have several subdomains for this app.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

https://gitlab.isb-sib.ch/calipho/nextprot-search/commit/8d9e022f3648c5df3390389a0b2c50d53501239c?view=parallel

```
if ($window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
                    ipCookie('nxprofile', profile);
                    ipCookie('nxtoken', token);
               } else {
                    ipCookie('nxprofile', profile, { domain: '.nextprot.org' });
                    ipCookie('nxtoken', token, { domain: '.nextprot.org' });
               }
```

Comment: Can you add more context for this answer? (e.g., how is the link relevant, _why_ does this code fix OP's issue)